# DELETE based on select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-delete

I have one very complicated SELECT, which fills temporary table with ids, based on which I need create DELETE query.

For example, temp table's rows looks like:

```
- first_id | second_id | third_id
 - 1   | 222 | 342
 - 1   | 222 | 343
 - 1   | 223 | 551
```

- ...

And query :

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE CONCAT(first_id, 'X', second_id, 'X', third_id) IN (SELECT CONCAT(first_id, 'X', second_id, 'X', third_id) FROM temp_table);
```

But this query IS too long. When I show PROCESSLIST, I see that this query time is about 4000s.

So my question is, how can I optimise DELETE query, to delete rows from one table based on select FROM another table and delete just rows based on 3 keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by removing the `CONCAT` and use an `JOIN` instead of a subquery, try something like :

```
DELETE mt FROM mytable mt INNER JOIN temp_table tt ON mt.first_id = tt.first_id AND mt.second_id = tt.second_id AND mt.third_id = tt.third_id
```

Comment: Thank you Omar, I did not know, that CONCAT and comparing rows are so slow. With join it tooks 7 seconds :)

Comment: Subqueries can have a big cost, as the result of a subquery is calculated for each row of the main query. So try to avoid them if you can !